# Why is G Suite passing DMARC when alignment fails?

Tags: email, security, dmarc

I have a G Suite account with a primary and secondary domains. I have successfully setup DMARC for my primary domain. Now I am trying to setup DMARC for my secondary domain.

SPF is setup for my primary and secondary domains to send from google:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com -all
```

DKIM is also setup for my primary and secondary domains. G Suite is configured for custom DKIM signing (so using my domains, not the `gappssmtp.com` domain.

DMARC is setup for my primary and secondary domains:

```
"v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:xxxx; ruf=mailto:yyyy;"
```

When I send an email from G Suite, using my secondary domain to another Gmail account, I notice the following:

Observation 1: `From:` address is correct as my secondary domain:

```
From: Matt <matt@secondarydomain.com>
```

Observation 2: DKIM signs using secondary domain correct:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=secondarydomain.com; s=google;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=...;
        b=...
```

Observation 3: SPF passes, but using my primary domain:

```
Return-Path: <matt@primarydomain.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of matt@primarydomain.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.41;
```

Observation 4: Gmail marks DMARC as *passed*:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@secondarydomain.com header.s=google header.b=r+g2VfEU;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of matt@primarydomain.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=matt@primarydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=secondarydomain.com
```

My understanding is that DMARC requires DKIM and SPF alignment, meaning `From:` and `Return-Path:` headers must both match. From what I can tell, this is not happening.

Why is Gmail reporting DMARC as *passed*? Incidentally, Outlook.com also reports a pass. However, when I send my email through various DMARC testers, they imply failure since it's not aligned.

**Follow-up Question:** Anyone know a way to get G Suite to set the `Return-Path` to my secondary domain when I send emails using my secondary domain?

**Update 2020-02-06: Answer to my follow-up question:**

I was sending emails from my secondary domain as an alias to my primary domain. The `Return-Path` will always be the "signed-in user". So in this case, it will always be my primary domain.

To resolve the `Return-Path` issue, I need to create a user on my secondary domain, and sign-in with that.

However, this still does not answer why Google passes the DMARC.

Answer (score 2):

DMARC requires **either SPF or DKIM** to produce a PASS result in alignment with the FROM domain.

Please see the [RFC for DMARC, section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-4.2):

> DMARC's filtering function is based on whether the RFC5322.From field
> domain is aligned with (matches) an authenticated domain name from **SPF
> *or* DKIM**. When a DMARC policy is published for the domain name found in
> the RFC5322.From field, and that domain name is not validated through
> **SPF *or* DKIM**, the disposition of that message can be affected by that
> DMARC policy when delivered to a participating receiver.

And also [section 6.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-6.6.2), step 5:

> [...]If **one or more** of the Authenticated [pass result] Identifiers [SPF or DKIM] align with the
> RFC5322.From domain, the message is considered to pass the DMARC
> mechanism check.[...]

In your case, the DKIM check produces a PASS result in alignment with the FROM domain and thus the DMARC check produces a PASS result.